# TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener onTabReselected called when just switch tab

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I set up `ViewPager` with `TabLayout` like this:

```java
tabLayoutOnPageChangeListener = new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout);

mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(tabLayoutOnPageChangeListener);

tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

so when I swipe `ViewPager`, `TabLayout` will update its indicator and selected tab; and when a tab is selected, `ViewPager` will change to proper page.

But this causes `onTabReselected` to be called even if I do not reselect tab, because after `onTabSelected`, `mViewPager.setCurrentItem()` will trigger tab selecting again (via `tabLayoutOnPageChangeListener`). I have to do this:

```java
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    mViewPager.removeOnPageChangeListener(tabLayoutOnPageChangeListener);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(tabLayoutOnPageChangeListener);
}
```

to temporary remove listener when `setCurrentItem()` is called.

Is there any "more right" way to make `ViewPager` work with `TabLayout`? I'm using latest v23.0.1 design support library.

Answer (score 1):

`TabLayout`'s [`setupWithViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)) method is available for this purpose. You should able to replace your code with `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)`.